# sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows убрать вверху сайта

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, opencart

Недавно заметил надпись "sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows" в самом вверху сайта fashion-milen.com. Нашел ее в header.tpl, строка: sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows
Но после удаления надпись осталась. Что это за надпись и как ее убрать? Я так понимаю это какой-то класс, только почему он показывается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

судя по загрузке с сайта. body приходит без этой строки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что значит что неправильно сформирован html. смотри в формировании

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

если из tpl удалил, то чисти кеш  smarty.

Comment: Я эту строку из header полностью удалял, но почему то надпись осталась..

Comment: у тебя скорее всего кеш надо почистить. ты какой фреймворк  юзаешь?

Comment: фреймфорк opencart 2.3, кеш чистил system/storage/cache/ и в браузере в инкогнито захожу

Comment: все таки смотри кеш, не бывает такого , что бы было из ниоткуда, да и инкогнито тоже кеширует. ctrl+shift+r часто помогает- это для браузера..а кеш смарти точно надо удалять. поиском по tpl прогони на эти строки ..может еще где выводится.

Comment: что за кеш смарти? кеш фрейморка чистил...

Comment: смарти -это шаблонизатор для php/ его юзают в опенкарте. может его ты и чистил ,а может там у  его свой кеш... тут я тебе не скажу.

Answer (score 1):

проблему решил, загвоздка была в кеше движка, почистил кеш модификаторов и строка исчезла.